# Increment value on multiple worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

Have an excel worksheet that has several worksheets that are all labeled differently, no pattern at all (ie; Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3 etc)
In the first worksheet on cell `B2` I have a value of `90` and would like every other worksheet to auto increment value by 1.
Would want second worksheet to have a value of `91` on `B2` and so on,,
I know i could tediously add `=SUM('WorksheetName'!B2 +1)` to do this but would take forever as i would have to manually type the sheet name each instance
Any way to add some VBA? or another formula?

To help clarify, 
My first worksheet is labeled `101` and has a value of `90` on cell B2
[image]

Comment: Yes you can do this with VBA. Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this should do what you want.

```
Sub x()

Dim i As Long, n As Long

n = 90

For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
    Sheets(i).Range("B1").Offset(i - 1).Value = n + i - 1
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: When running this the value does increase but so does the cell #. Need the value to increase by 1 in the same cell on each sheet

Comment: You said in your question "Would want second worksheet to have a value of 91 on **B2** and so on". Remove the offset bit if not.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Another example of how to accomplish the task.  Added check for original worksheet

```
Sub SetWorksheetValues()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim firstWS As Worksheet
Dim cValue As Long
Dim counter As Long
'set the counter to 2
counter = 2
'set the first worksheet that has our beginning value
Set firstWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("101")
'get the value and increment by 1
cValue = firstWS.Range("B1").Value + 1
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        'skip the worksheet with our starting value
        If ws.Name <> firstWS.Name Then
            'set the cell value
            ws.Range("B" & counter).Value = cValue
            'increment each value by 1
            cValue = cValue + 1
            counter = counter + 1
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

to test it

create a workbook and add a module in it.
run the following macro

```
Sub AddLotsOfWorksheets()
Dim i As Long
Dim c As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
c = 101
    For i = 1 To 250
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(Before:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count))
        ws.Name = CStr(c)
        c = c + 1
    Next i
End Sub
```

add 1 (or 90) in B1 on sheet 101

Run the SetWorksheetValues

sheet 350 cell B250 should have a value of 250 if 1 was entered 
or 
339 if 90 was entered.

Comment: I ran this and it incremented only the second worksheet (which is labeled 103) all the rest did not increment

Comment: I tested this with a workbook with 250 sheets and it incremented correctly.

Comment: It does work when i created a new workbook and ran the script you provided. It did, however, increment the cell as well. 101 has 90 in B1; 102 has 91 in B2; 103 has 92 in B3 etc. I am adding a picture to show VBA with my workbooks